# I'm trying to use my string list indecies as my checkboxs cunstruct variable's names but I get error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to use my list indices as the checkbox  construct variable names but I get an error:

> A local or parameter named 'item' cannot be declared in this scope
>   because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a
>   local or parameter

```
List<string> boxNames = new List<string>();
 for (int i=0;i<Treat_departments.Count;i++)
 {
   boxNames.Add("B" + i.ToString());
 }

foreach( string item in Treat_departments)
 {

  CheckBox item = new CheckBox();
 }
```

//I just did it in python and it works properly

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear:  you have declared a variable called `item` in the `foreach` cycle.
Then you are trying to declare another variable with the same name `item` inside the `foreach`, you can't do that.

Moreover, you cant cast a string variable as a checkbox, it's not fully clear to me what are you trying to do, maybe this?

```
List<string> boxNames = new List<string>();
 for (int i=0;i<Treat_departments.Count;i++)
 {
   boxNames.Add("B" + i.ToString());
 }

foreach( string item in Treat_departments)
 {
  CheckBox itemBox = new CheckBox({ text = item });
 }
```

or

```
foreach( string item in Treat_departments)
 {
  CheckBox itemBox = new CheckBox({ name = item });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate variable names declared in the foreach loop and in the inner part of the loop. Change the name of either `item` and it will work.